# Why the value of this expression “1 == 1 and 0 or 0.1” equals 0.1 in python?

Tags: python

Why the value of this expression “1 == 1 and 0 or 0.1” equals 0.1 in python?
[image]

Comment: This is `(((1 == 1) and 0) or 0.1)`. The answers below should probably start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What are `and` and `or`?

`a and b` is a fancy way of writing `a if not a else b`. That is, if `a` is falsy, return it because falsy and anything is falsy. Otherwise, return `b`.

`a or b` is a fancy way of writing `a if a else b`. That is, if `a` is truthy, return it because truthy or anything is truthy. Otherwise, return `b`.

So, `and` and `or` don't necessarily return boolean values.

`1 == 1 and 0 or 0.1` is `(1 == 1 and 0) or 0.1` because `and` has higher precedence than `or`; `1 == 1 and 0` is `1 == 1 if not 1 == 1 else 0`; clearly `1 == 1` so the result is `0`. The final expression is `0 or 0.1` which is `0 if 0 else 0.1` and clearly `0` is falsy so we get `0.1`.

Note that `and` short-circuits for falsy left (allowing you to do things like `x < len(l) and l[x] == k`, and `or` short-circuits for truthy left.

Answer (score 2):

This is the case:

```
1 == 1 => True
True and 0 => 0
0 or 0.1 => 0.1
```

**You can open your REPL to simulate it.**

---

**I think that what confuse you is that you maybe think that the or/and operation must return boolean value.**

**But, that not the case, they return the actual value participate in comparation.**

Answer (score 0):

`1==1` means true. 
`bool and a or b` like `bool?a:b` in C.

But now it is a special case `a = 0`,In this case, the `b` will return.

This expression `bool?a:b` will fail.It will do like this:

`1==1` is true , `a` is false.So `1==1 and a` is false

Then, `false or b` is b.

Answer (score 0):

If you've ever learned the order of operations in school, you know that exponents are evaluated before multiplication/division.

In the same sense, Python has an [order of operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), where the operators [`and`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) and [`or`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) have very low precedence. What is important for you to know is that `and` has a lower precedence than `or`, and an equality comparison, `==`, has a higher precedence than both.

```
1 == 1 and 0 or 0.1
```

The above will evaluate in the following order:

```
>>> 1 == 1        # equality comparison evaluates to True
True
>>> True and 0    # boolean AND evaluates to 0
0
>>> 0 or 0.1      # boolean OR evaluates to 0.1
0.1
```